# chrome v69.0.3497.81 flash settings

Tags: flash

Since the recent upgraded Chrome v69.0.3497.81, the Flash settings do not allow me to "add" trusted sites to the Flash settings (there is no add button present any longer); the setting is currently set to "ask first (recommended)" but it never asks and the requests involving the use of Flash will not execute.

Comment: I just checked my browser(which is up to date) I could find the option to add sites here. chrome://settings/content/flash

Comment: There is no "add" option under the "block" or "allow" area.

Comment: I've observed this as well, and the sites that are added by browsing to them are removed next time Chrome is started. This is a new change and I would guess it will further force sites to stop using Flash, or use a different browser that isn't to aggressively trying to tell people what they can and can't use in their site coding.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Type this URL into Chrome: `chrome://flags`.
2. When the page loads, enter `ephemeral flash` into the search box.
3. For the setting `Enable Ephemeral Flash Permissions`, change the value to `disabled`.
4. Reload the browser. Chrome should work the way it did before this version.

Comment: Oh, that's a good solution. Thanks for things and have an upvote. I assumed there was a setting for this due to the rather substantial changes they pushed in recent versions.